# After installation module django version switched to lowest version

Tags: python, django

I am working on project which use django as main project library. I faced with a need to install for this project new module `django-inspect-model` and `django-inspect` after playing with both i understood that these modules aren't appropriate solutions for me and i uninstall them by

```
pip uninstall django-inspect-model
```

I don't remember but when i was installing one of these modules i saw in console message about compatibility with my django version but i didnt pay attention for it. Because module was succesfully installed and after deinstallation both of them i tried to run

```
python manage.py shell
```

which didn't run and printed in console that some of my installed modules imporerly configured for example celery. After googling message about error i understand that this kind of errors rise due to incompatibility with django and i decided to check my django version by

```
python -c "import django;print(django.__version__)"
```

Which promted me that installed django version is 1.8.6 but i exactly knew that  before above described actions my django's version was 2.2.0
After checking of my requirements.txt file there isn't a doubt that installed django version was 2.2.0. How it's possible that installed module can switch django on lowest version than it was? Is here anyone who faced with the same situation ? What if i only upgrade my project installed modules (django too) using the same requirements.txt? I am afraid that my actions can broke my whole project

Comment: what does your `pip freeze` say?

Comment: @n1rna i was expecting help from community but not to wait up and upgraded my django version and it worked. I will try to reproduce above described behaviour on another project to research why this problem was arrised

Answer (score 0):

While installing some packages, Django switches to lower versions due to compatibility issues. In case you want the previous version back, you need to upgrade your Django with the following command:

```
python -m pip install -U Django
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade django
```